# How to easily connect to this PCB?

Tags: pcb

I got this board I need to connect to. The 3 connectors are about 5mm long all together. I can see bigger pins/connectors online but not this small. I did solder but it takes time to do so for every device.

Is there a way to connect easily to them other than soldering?

[image]

Comment: Perhaps 2mm?  Is this a temporary connection or lasting?   You could solder in a header and then use a 3-pin female jumper, or possibly hold one sideways with finger pressure or make a Pogo pin fixture... **more details of requirement needed**

Comment: I need stable connection for a few minutes, can't hold with my hand. Soldering anything on top is challenging, looking for something to plug in and use right away. How do these companies connect to them when flashing the original firmware?

Comment: Pogo pin fixture then, probably P50's or maybe P75's.  You need to do a better measuring job, can you take a straight on photo with a .100 header strip across them, it will be too big but the detailed comparison will show what you have.  Or maybe Pomona micrograbbers but they may fall off.

Comment: If you can find the correct through-hole connector it may sit in the holes and make good contact as long as you push on it slightly (sideways, not downward).

Answer (score 0):

yes, assuming you wan this for temporary connection for application like testing etc. There are connectors/pins available which are spring loaded. take breadboard (general purpose) or copper clad pcb, make holes to match your PCB pin pitch (use drill), isolate those holes using knife cutter , Mount spring loaded connector. make you wire connection to this copper clad PCB.
Now your bottom board is ready which has spring loaded connector, Now all you need to do is place this DUT PCB (in pic) on top of your new created PCB match pins and you are all set.